# Cannot run the procedure

Tags: netlogo

Can someone help me get around the error coming in the procedure below when the code if run. At runtime, it gives an

> error messsage: "Expected a literal value"

Thanks

```
to slow-down-car [ car-ahead ] ;; turtle procedure
[ speed ] of car-ahead - deceleration

]
if speed != 0 [ set speed deceleration ]
set patience patience - 1
end
```

Comment: What is this code supposed to do? I'm not sure what the intent behind it was, so I'm not sure what fix to suggest. I'm particularly confused by the `[speed] of car-ahead - deceleration ]` part, it seems like a fragment rather than a complete thought.

Comment: i think you are trying to set the speed of the car, in which case you probably want `set speed [ speed ] of car-ahead - deceleration`

Answer (score 0):

You have a few syntax errors:

```
[ speed ] of car-ahead - deceleration

]
```

Notice you have one too many ]'s at the bottom. Also, the statement `[ speed ] of car-ahead - deceleration` doesn't make any sense. Are you trying to assign this to a variable?